# Java Web Services Indicating Requirement Levels of Attributes

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I have implemented web services at my application. When I want to send an object to my server via web services over SOA with Soap UI I get something like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:impl="http://impl.arg.lou.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <impl:addStudent>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <student>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>?</name>
         </student>
      </impl:addStudent>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I don't want name field to be optional, it should be a required field. How can I do it?

I use Apache cxf.

Link for Requirement Levels: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt

Comment: You should change the title of your question: you are asking for adding restrictions to web services messages right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web services definition you have a *type* section that defines the XML schema of your message. In that definition you can set several constraints, like "required fields".

**Example:**

```
<wsdl:definitions name="myService" ...>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="myNameSpace" xmlns:tns="myNameSpace">
      <xs:complexType name="studentType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:element name="student" nillable="false" type="tns:studentType"/>
    </xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  ...
 </wsdl:definitions>
```

Now, this will not be validated in the server side if you do not activate the schema validation in your apache CXF configuration like this:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="myService" ...>
  <jaxws:properties>
    <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="true" />
    ...
  </jaxws:properties>
  ...
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

**PS: SOAP UI use the XML schema of the targeted web service to generate the default request. If the XML schema does not have the `use="required"` or `nillable="false"` it will add an `<!-- optional -->` comment on the element**

Comment: Can I do it with annotations just before the definition of a variable at Java class?

Comment: If you are using JAXWS and JAXB with a "first code" approach, you can use the JAXB annotations like `@XmlElement(nillable=false)` and `@XmlAttribute(required=false)`